# Prove that directional derivative of scalar field outlines a circle

Tags: solution-verification, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, scalar-fields

[image: Directional derivative proof]

I have to show that if we draw the derivatives $d\phi/ds$ from one point $P$ of the scalar field in every direction, the ends of the line segments representing the value of $d\phi/ds$ will lie on a circle (or a sphere, but I'm limiting the problem to 2D).
$\phi$ is an equiscalar surface.

I've used law of cosines to define $a$ (in the figure):
$$a^2=(\nabla\phi/2)^2+(\frac{d\phi}{ds})^2-\nabla\phi\frac{d\phi}{ds}\cos{\alpha}$$
I would now like to show that $a=const$ but I don't know how. I've tried choosing different direction $\hat{e}$ and obtaining another equation from law of cosines but it seemed pointless.

Comment: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Gradient_of_potential.svg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally figured this out and thought of sharing.
The main trick is to write $d\phi/ds$ as
$$d\phi/ds=\nabla\phi\cdot\hat{e}=\nabla\phi\cos{\angle\nabla\phi,\hat{e}}$$
So we have
$$a^2=(\nabla\phi/2)^2+(d\phi/ds)^2−\nabla\phi d\phi/ds\cos{\alpha}$$
$$a^2=(\nabla\phi/2)^2+\nabla\phi^2\cos^2{\alpha}−\nabla\phi \nabla\phi\cos{\alpha}\cos{\alpha}$$
$$a^2=(\nabla\phi/2)^2+\nabla\phi^2\cos^2{\alpha}−\nabla\phi^2\cos^2{\alpha}$$
$$a^2=(\nabla\phi/2)^2$$
$$a>0$$
$$a=(\nabla\phi/2)=const$$